# WSO2IS openid-connect : Access control using access-token

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I use WSO2IS as an OIDC provider for authentication and authorization. Using Authentication Code grant, I got the access-token. I need to authorize the users to access specific services based on their roles.

I tried to use XACML to solve this, but I found that I need to pass base64 encoding of username:password in the header of REST API XACML request. Instead is there any way I can authorize the user to access services based on their roles, using access-token ?

This part of authorization happens in the resource server. I thought I could use the introspection endpoint to authorize the user based on the access token using scopes. But I don't understand how scopes can be used to provide access control to the users ?

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token with all scopes available to a user, the OAuth2 client must request all scopes it cares about and the token will contain only those that the user has access to. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416297/how-to-get-all-the-scopes-user-has-access-to-in-wso2-api-manager).

Yes, it's cumbersome, but OAuth2 is primarily an authorization delegation protocol - it allows users to delegate some of their rights (scopes) to a client.

Alternatively, if you could decide permissions based on roles, you could probably get a list of user roles from an ID token.

Comment: How can I add/map user roles in id token in WSO2IS ? Now I just get fields like at_hash, acr, sub, aud, azp, name, iss etc. in the id_token.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, roles (as a claim) are not covered by the OpenID Connect RFC, but they could be provided by your implementation. There is also the `userinfo` endpoint which could give you the info if the access token allows it.

Comment: Went through the post to get scopes for a user. But is WSO2 API Manager the only way to add scopes ? Can't we do it just with WSO2 IS ? My requirement simple. Each user has different privileges, like user1 can access service1 and user2 can access service2. I just need the privileges of the user/role as simple as a key value pair, [User1:Service1], [User2:Service2].  It need not be an access to REST API. But I see that in WSO2IS, privileges are mapped to API endpoints and HTTP actions like GET, POST and access control happens only through these APIs. Why is it so ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with WSO2, so I cannot help you with its configuration.